# How can i listen to telegram webhooks using python on the hosted server?

Tags: python, flask, telegram, webhooks, host

I've got a hosting, and a domain name, i want to listen to telegram webhooks.
First thing first i decided to make a simple flask application to understand flask and requests. But when i tried to start my simple app it deployed on localhost. Can you explain me how to deploy it on external ip and on my domain name?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, you will need to use a hosting provider, like Amazon Web Services (AWS), Google Cloud, Microsoft Azure, etc. Because you are hosting a simple flask app, I would reccomend Heroku to get started. In order to host it on your domain name, [simply reroute the domain to the ip address of the server using the "A" record of the domain.](https://www.servers.com/support/knowledge/dedicated-servers/how-to-point-your-domain-name-to-dedicated-servers-ip-address) I would suggest to start researching what hosting providers are, what the cloud is and how it works, and how dns works, and then try hosting your app. I personally use AWS to host my flask apps, and it can be tricky to start with, but over time it is a very useful skill to have, and overtime with AWS you can deploy ultra-optimized, production grade applications for millions of users worldwide. Don't feel overwhelmed when you first start on this journey learning about the cloud, DNS, and such, instead stay optimistic and keep exploring, and if you have any more questions regarding the internet, feel free to post it on this site :)